# Random value in Tree (Scala)

Tags: scala

I'm working with `Tree.scala` defined in Functional Programming in Scala. I have implemented all the functions I needed but I have one more that I'm trying to do. The concept is to generate with a RNG home-made, a value between 1 and the numbers of leaves in the Tree (function `count`). The generated value represents the position of the value. So for example, if the generated value is 3, I will return the leaf at the 3rd position from left to right.

[Data structure of a Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRWWU.png)

So I've made this function (according `n` is the random number generated):

```
def loop[A](tree: Tree[A], n: Int): A = tree match {
    case Leaf(a) => if (n == 0) a else loop(tree, n - 1)
    case Branch(left, right) => Branch(loop(left, n), loop(right, n))
}
```

The idea behind this is, if `n > 0` and we are on a leaf, then we can minus a position, if `n == 0` we return the value, and if we are on a branch we continue to travel the tree. But it's not working and I'm in lack of ideas, I also tried some things before but without the expected result.

Comment: The problem is that you keep looping over the same tree once you reach a `Leaf` thus you will always return the first `Leaf` _(also the `Branch` code has the wrong return type)_ - What you need to do is to keep a stack of work pending to do; so that wen you reach a `Leaf` that was not what you wanted, then you can continue with the others. - You may also, first write a method that collects all the `Leafs` as a sorted `List`

Comment: Yea thats what I did, thanks for the answer!